# Jest/Enzyme/JSDOM document.body.createTextRange is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, enzyme, jsdom

I'm trying to test a react component, and I seem to be hitting a JSDOM issue.

When I mount my component;

```
const component = mount(
   <PipelineActions pipelineActions={value} {...actions} />
);
```

I get an error thrown;

> document.body.createTextRange is not a function

I tried setting the dom directly via;

```
(global as any).document = jsdom.jsdom('');
(global as any).window = document.defaultView;
```

which had no effect. When I try to `console.log(document.body)` I get something odd as well;

> HTMLBodyElement {}

It seems like the DOM isn't getting built right, but I'm not sure why. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: The fix is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572682/createtextrange-is-not-working-in-chrome/46424247#46424247

Answer (score 0):

You can set and mock stuff on the `global` object:

```
global.body = {createTextRange: jest.fn()}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I get `TypeError: Cannot set property 'createTextRange' of undefined`.

Comment: Updated my answer