# functions from document class missing in typescript version

Tags: typescript

We are migrating from javascript to typescript and some of the functions from document class doesn't seem to exists any more. I can't find anything equivalent.

```
 1) createRange()
          var textRange = document.getSelection().createRange();
 2)createTextRange
          var preCaretTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
 3)focus()
        var el : Node= document.getElementById(divId).childNodes[0];
           el.focus();
```

[image: Picture is worth a thousand words]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object doesn't have the `createRange` method (can also be seen in the [lib.d.ts definition](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L15518)).
Instead you should use [document.createRange](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L7600):

```
var textRange = document.createRange();
```

(2) The `createTextRange` is an IE only thing ([CreateTextRange is not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572682/createtextrange-is-not-working-in-chrome)), it's not a standard.
There's an issue for that: ['createTextRange' seems to be missing from 'lib.dom.d.ts' and other including libs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10181) which says:

> this is a break because this is an IE-only API. Users can augment the
>   interfaces if necessary

So you can do this:

```
interface TextRange {
    ...
}

interface HtmlElement {
    createTextRange(): TextRange;
}
```

(3) The `focus()` part works well, the compiler has no issues with it.

---

#### Edit

The Node object doesn't have the `focus()` method, so you need to cast it:

```
var el = document.getElementById(divId).childNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
el.focus(); // works now
```

Comment: Thank you! focus() issue is still there , I have updated the question. How do I resolve issue #2?

Comment: Check my revised answer concerning `focus`, as for the 2nd issue, as the quote says you need to "augment the interfaces", and I gave you a short snippet as an example of how to do that

Comment: I was directed to this answer, but I still get compile errors, such as `Argument of type 'Range' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TextRange'.`

Comment: @yondaimehokage There's no such type as `TextRange`, are you adding it yourself as shown in the answer?